# How to fix drill hole in metal desk

Tags: screws, drill, metal, desk

I ordered this desk [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RXXQ1M8) but one of the sides' holes in one of the legs won't allow any of the screws to screw in.

What are my options? It's definitely the screw the directions are saying to use but I guess the hole itself isn't threaded or something?

Or could these holes be a different size? And I just need to go to Lowe's to look for smaller screws? I'm really lost here and returning the desk isn't an option sadly.

[image: Holes that won't allow the correct screw to screw in]

Comment: While Jimmy Fix-it's answer is _very_ good (and correct), before attempting to fix it on your own, I'd suggest contacting the mfgr to ask about replacement parts. I've just had a similar issue with a flat-pack dresser and was pleasantly shocked at the very positive response from the mfgr. They're shipping 3 new parts since the originals didn't have properly located assembly holes. They indicated that if this doesn't fix the issue, I can still return it to the original retailer (dealing with the retailer). If _they_ become a pain, I'll figure out how to fix it myself.

Comment: Would you please post the page in the instructions pertaining to that assembly step? Maybe you've misunderstood something.

Answer (score 2):

Just bring that original screw to a hardware store (I would say for you NOT to go to a "big-box" store because it might be helpful for you to speak to a human for assistance) and ask for a *sheet metal screw" that is approximately the same diameter. A *sheet metal screw* will be a threaded screw not unlike your original, but will be pointed and is designed to carve its own thread into the metal as you drive it in. Sheet metal screws will not "tap" new threads which would allow you to use a *machine screw* like your original, but it should drive in and hold just fine.

Comment: Also known as a "self-tapping" screw

Comment: If the hole is there, but the threads won't engage properly, it could be that some weld slag fell into the threads.  If this is the case, you would have to re-tap the threads.

Comment: Are you sure that hole is intended to be threaded?  The countersink suggest to me that a flathead bolt is supposed to fit in there, perhaps to tie this desk together with another desk, credenza, drawer stack or filing cabinet.

Comment: I'm not sure that those are countersunk so much as punched.